# IV2SLS output summary much different than previous OLS estimation

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, sandbox

I ran a different version of Mincer´s equation to estimate salary. Firstly, I ran an OLS version without considering endogeneity and the results are the following:[Output summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCgUu.png)

Salario is actually the natural log of it.
After that, I wrote next code to get an estimation with 2SLS method to solve endogeneity in variables No_Feliz and Años_Edu using No_Dep and max_edu_padres as instrumental variables for each one. However, the output is a bit confusing and I don´t know how to deal with it.

```
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm import IV2SLS

resultIV = IV2SLS(_dfb['Salario'], _dfb[['No_Feliz','Años_Edu']], _dfb[['No_Dep','Estatura','Años_Expe','Edad','Edad_2','Peso','Peso_2','DI','D_Hombre']]).fit() 

resultIV.summary()
```

Results: [Output summary IV2SLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pirgd.png)

It´s clear the output has some issues (R2 too high compared to ols result, no result for F-statistic, coef of No_Feliz has a positive sign while it's negative in OLS estimation, the other exogenous variables are not taken into account despite the fact I included them)
I´d appreciate if someone could help me to fix it or at least make things a bit more clear to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: you only specify that there are two explanatory variables in the main regression `_dfb[['No_Feliz','Años_Edu']]` which does not include a constant and none of the other regressors that you have in the OLS model. For R2, see answers how the definition changes if there is no constant in the regressor matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `statsmodels`'s sandbox version which is not well tested.  Instead use `linearmodels`. It is fully tested and correct.

Start by installing using `pip install linearmodels`

Then you need to be explicit about which variables are endogenous and need instrumenting, which are exogenous so in the model but not instrumented, and which are instruments only.

```py
from linearmodels import IV2SLS

dep = _dfb['Salario']
exog = None
endog = _dfb[['No_Feliz','Años_Edu']] 
instr = _dfb[['No_Dep','Estatura','Años_Expe','Edad','Edad_2','Peso','Peso_2','DI','D_Hombre']]

resultIV = IV2SLS(dep, exog, endog, instr).fit() 

resultIV.summary  # Note: this is a property so no ()
```

You can find the [help which has more details](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/iv/iv/linearmodels.iv.model.IV2SLS.html). There are also some [examples](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/iv/examples/basic-examples.html).